# Python socket server gets signal only once

Tags: python, sockets

im just getting into the networking and i wanted to try something with pinging

server code:

```
import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 5050
backlog = 5
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)
    print "getting "+str(data)+" from "+ str(address)
```

client code

```
import socket
import time

host = 'localhost'
port = 5050
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
while 1:
    s.send('PING')
    print "sending package"
    time.sleep(1)
```

now it outputs:

```
getting PING from ('127.0.0.1', 56580)
```

only once, while it should get a PING every second.

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only make *one* connection to your server, you only need to call `.accept()` once, to accept that connection. Once open, the socket will receive the periodic packets you send from your client.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
client, address = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = client.recv(size)
    print "getting "+str(data)+" from "+ str(address)
```

Comment: @MichaelvdNet: did you restart your client too? I tested this just now, works fine. All I did was move the `s.accept()` line outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're only reading once. Either call `client.recv` in a loop on the server:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()
    # TODO Use fork(), threading, or async I/O to for parallel processing
    while True: 
        data = client.recv(size)
        print "getting "+str(data)+" from "+ str(address)
```

or create a socket for every ping:

```
while True:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host,port))
    s.send('PING')
    print "sending package"
    time.sleep(1)
```